# JQM; Not able to generate a confirmation message before app exit

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to exit my app if I am on my Index page and have hit the back button from my mobile device. For this I have created a data-role="popup" on my Index page and on back event i am trying to call it however not successful i.e. I do not get any popup. Can some one please help me out on this.

I have tried various options available as post on StackExchange but was not successful.

Below is my code.

If I add an alert message instead of **$('#popupMainClose').popup('open');** I get that alert, however the popup message does not open.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Genie</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if (direction == 'back') {
        alert($('.ui-page-active').attr('id'));
        if ( $('.ui-page-active').attr('id') == 'mainpage') {
            $('#popupMainClose').popup('open');
        };
    }
});
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-id="commonHeader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Genie</h1>
            <a id="btnMainLogin" href="#Login" rel="external" data-icon="home">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="mainlist" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupMainClose" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
                <h1>Exit</h1>
            </div>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a> 
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">

                <h1>Are you sure you want to exit?</h1>
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" onClick=closeApplication(0)>No</a>  
                <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" onClick=closeApplication(1)>Yes</a>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did anyone manage to get some headway... I am struggling from past couple of days. Need some help :-(

Comment: Use a dialog instead of a popup,the popup within the page is hidden once navigate event is fired. While dialog acts like a page, it can be shown.

Comment: Or `return false;` after opening the popup.

Comment: Hi Omar, you made my day :-). Thanks a ton. However I am not sure how do i stop "back" navigation when the user has clicked NO from the dialog box. Do you have any clue?

Comment: You're welcome. Use either `$.mobile.changePage()` if it doesn't work, use `window.location.href = URL;`

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. What I meant was irrespective of I click on YES or NO from the dialog box, my back navigates back. I want to stop that. I want that whenever I click on NO I should remain on the same page from where dialog box got initiated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. This is for people who are struggling with this issue. You need to use Dialog instead of Popup. Kindly read Omar's comments above. Thanks ones again Omar

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
<title>Genie</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
    var direction = data.state.direction;
    if (direction == 'back') {
        if ( $('.ui-page-active').attr('id') == 'mainpage') {
            window.location = "#popupMainClose";
        };
    }
});
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">
        <div data-id="commonHeader" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Genie</h1>
            <a id="btnMainLogin" href="#Login" rel="external" data-icon="home">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="mainlist" data-role="listview"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="dialog" id="popupMainClose">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
            <h1>Exit</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
            <h1>Are you sure you want to exit?</h1>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" onClick=closeApplication(0)>No</a>  
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b" onClick=closeApplication(1)>Yes</a>  
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```